# Multiple Response Crosstabs in R

Tags: r

I am new to RStudio and i want to have a multiple response crosstabs with multiple banner, I have here a data:

```
  gender age_group Q19_1 Q19_2 Q19_3 ....
1 female          1     0     1     1 ....
2 female          2     1     1     0 ....
3 male            3     0     1     1 ....
4 female          4     1     0     0 ....
5 male            2     0     1     1 ....
6 male            3     1     0     0 ....
7 female          1     1     1     1 ....
8 female          4     0     1     1 ....
9 male            1     1     0     0 ....
```

and my desired output is a table like this,

```
          |gender        |age group                  |
          |male  |female |1     |2     |3     |4     |             
Q19_1     |2     |3      |2     |1     |1     |1     |             
Q19_2     |2     |4      |2     |2     |1     |1     |             
Q19_3     |2     |3      |2     |1     |1     |1     |
...
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: See base R function `ftable`.

Comment: Hi @RuiBarradas, thank you very much. Upon checking, if I am not mistaken, ftable is used for "Multi-Level" crosstabs. Here in my example, I wish to have a single level rows (multiple response variable), with multiple banners (column) variable.

Comment: You cannot do that in R, at least not in the form of a table. You can produce a document printing what you posted or you can create a list with members `gender` and `age.group`. Each of these list members would then be those data.frames.